# How to remove UITableView top inset when embedded in ContainerView?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, storyboard, uicontainerview

I am currently working on an iPhone App. I now have a problem with the top spacing inset of a UITableView. See this screenshot:

[image: App Running. See the space?]

There should be no space between the table view cells and the buttons.

I do not know how to fix this. The UITableView is embedded in a ContainerView like this:

[image: Storyboard View Controller]

I think I got the container view constraints right. Top Space to Chapter Button is set to `0`.

[image: Container View Constraints]

I tried to change some settings of the table view controller in storyboard. For example the `Adjust Scroll View Insets`. However it does not change anything when I disable that.

[image: TableViewController Settings]

I also tried to set the TableView insets directly in the code in `viewDidLoad()`:

`tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)`

However this also did not fix it.

Can anyone help? I have no idea where to look.

Comment: Have you embed navigation controller?

Comment: It is a ViewController that is shown by a push segue from a view controller which is embedded in a navigation controller. I also added the navigation bar via storyboard to the view controller to customize its bar button items after it has been pushed.

Comment: do you want to hide first cell of uitableview ??

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This can be solved by disabling auto adjustment of scroll view insets. However this setting has to be applied to the ViewController **which contains the ContainerView (with the UITableView inside of it)**. It does not work when applied to the UITableView itself.

This can be done via Storyboard:

[image: adjust scroll view insets]

Or via code in `viewDidLoad()`: `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false`

Comment: This has been deprecated: `'automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets' was deprecated in iOS 11.0: Use UIScrollView's contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior instead`

Comment: e.g. `tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never`

Answer (score 15):

Since iOS 15 there's a new parameter which can introduce a top gap when using a section header. This can be removed with the following:

```
if #available(iOS 15, *) {
    tableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = 0
}
```

Comment: This was happening for me even without having section headers. Your solution fixed it for me, thanks 

Answer (score 2):

Try this Hope this work.
hide **View which contains the ContainerView.**

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help. I also can not hide the navigation bar, because I need it.

Comment: Now I fixed it! I had to disable `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets`. But not in the UITableView in the Container but in the View which contains the ContainerView.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added an answer above which explains the solution completly.